# DB administration site for Spring + JPA project

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa

I would like to know how if there is any way to automatically generate a database administration site for a Spring + JPA project. It should take the annotated JPA entities and dynamically generate the site to keep track of any change in the domain Java classes.

I am looking for something similar to the Django admin site (I think you can also do the same with Ruby on Rails), that allows the user:

- to see and update the data in the different tables without developing any extra code
- to handle relations between tables, different kind of data (numbers, dates, etc)

In the Java world I am only aware of [Spring Roo](https://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/), but it does not fit my needs because I want to integrate it into an already existing third-party project.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Play! Framework's CRUD Module](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/crud)

Comment: It would be great to see that solution integrated as part of Spring MVC + Spring Data, to avoid the need to develop an extra application with a different framework.