# Data administration site for SpringBoot/SpringData JPA?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm building a site with `SpringBoot` and `SpringData JPA`. Do either of these provide support for an out-of-the-box administration site generated auto-magically from the repositry definitions so that you can manage the data in a CRUD fashion?

Similar to something like the admin site functionality `Django` comes with: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Google searches for `SpringBoot Admin site` all point to https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin which is more around administering the config for `SpringBoot` itself, which is not what I'm after.

I did find this older question but it's a good few years old now:
[DB administration site for Spring + JPA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153150/db-administration-site-for-spring-jpa-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature available in Spring Boot or Spring Data (JPA/JDBC/...).

What you could get out-of-the-box are RESTful endpoints to perform CRUD operations via HTTP with [Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a few years since this question has been asked, but I started working on an open source library that provides a CRUD web UI for Spring Boot/JPA apps just recently. You can find it at https://github.com/aileftech/spring-boot-database-admin.

I'm happy to receive any feedback if somebody gives it a try. It's still in a very early stage so it might break with untested Spring Boot/JPA configurations, but it should work fine for several of the most common ones.